# document.getElementById and using classname

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following in HTML code:

```
<div id="story" class="componentBox">
  <h1 class="articleTitle">Parlamentarzyści nie stracą emerytur</h1>
  <div class="artDetails">19 kwietnia 2016 | Kraj |  Wiktor Ferfecki</div>
  <div class="storyContent">
```

To retrieve the contents of `articleTitle` I use:

```
document.getElementById("story").getElementsByTagName("div")[0].innertext
```

And to retrieve the contents of `artDetails`

```
document.getElementById("story").getElementsByTagName("div")[0].innertext
```

I think that it would be better to make use of the titles i.e. `articleTitle` and `artDetails`. I have no clues how to do it whatsoever. I've tried `document.getElementById("story").getElementByClassName("articleTitle")[0].innertext` but it throws and error.

Comment: use `querySelector` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) to select an element and use [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) property on HTMLNode to get the text content of the element.

```
var title = document.querySelector('#story .articleTitle').textContent;

var details = document.querySelector('#story .artDetails').textContent;
```

```js
var title = document.querySelector('#story .articleTitle').textContent;
var details = document.querySelector('#story .artDetails').textContent;

document.body.innerHTML = 'Title: ' + title + '<br /> Details: ' + details;
```

```html
<div id="story" class="componentBox">
  <h1 class="articleTitle">Parlamentarzyści nie stracą emerytur</h1>
  <div class="artDetails">19 kwietnia 2016 | Kraj | Wiktor Ferfecki</div>
  <div class="storyContent">
```

Comment: Both answers are perfect. The one I'd like to accept was first hence the decision.

Answer (score 2):

While you can use the [`document.GetElementsByClassName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) function to target specific classes, if you want to target a specific element, you may be better off using the [`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) function as seen below :

```
// Get the title (i.e. the "articleTitle" class below an element with ID "story"
var title = document.querySelector('#story .articleTitle').textContent;
// Do the same for the details...
var details = document.querySelector('#story .artDetails').textContent;
```

You can see a [working example here](http://jsbin.com/joyeram/1/edit?js,output) and demonstrated below :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'd *highly recommend* looking into [jQuery](https://jquery.com/).  It will help you do more with less.  So instead of doing this:

```
document.getElementById("story").getElementsByTagName("div")[0].innertext
```

You could write this:

```
$('#story .artDetails')[0].innertext
```

And you would still accomplish the same thing.